# How can I overlap videos in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking to make an iPhone app that plays videos that can overlap. Like this:

[image]

How might I do this?

Comment: So… what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

1) Inefficient way :  If you want to play all media simultaneously. 
Grid View of mediaplayers.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView     cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // get URL 
    Player *mediaPlayer = [[self playerArray]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:mediaPlayer.url];
    MPMoviePlayerController* mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [mPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [mPlayer play];

    //For viewing partially.....
    [mPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(/*Your frame*/)];
    [mPlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; 
    [cell addSubview:mPlayer.view];  

    return cell;

}
```

2) Efficient way: Place the grid with thumbnails and replace media player object with UIImageview when user taps on a cell (in this case place the above code in didSelectRow )